# Multer, Multer-s3 not calling callbacks for dynamic key naming

Tags: express, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3, filepond

I'm trying to pipe a file that I send with FilePond for React, get with on my expressjs and upload to s3 with multer and multer-s3. I have seen tutorials that specify that the best way to name the files dynamically is to declare a callback on the key but if I do not set a value directly, it simply ignores is and the whole multer middleware sends a success message.

Here is what I'm doing in express:

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: aws_bucket_name,
    ACL: "public-read",
    key: (req, file, cb) => {
      console.log("This never gets called");
      console.log(req.body);
      console.log(file);
      cb(null, `avatars/${req.params.uid}`);
    }
  })
});

app.post('/avatar/:uid', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("this gets called")
  res.send("uploaded")
});

I'm using ES6, and am doing exactly as the documentation suggests. Any ideas why this might not be working?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried not using ES6 syntax in the `key` part in multer config?

Comment: Yes. With far arrow function you mean

Comment: well your code looks fine though, can you share me how do you call this api in Postman?